How to Hold Charge at Checkout and Confirm Stock Availability in Magento 2 Using Stripe
How can I achieve the following requirements in Magento 2?

Hold the charge for the product at checkout using Stripe.
After the order is placed, send an email to the customer with the message: "Your order is on hold. We will get back to you once we confirm stock availability."
Once stock availability is confirmed with the vendor, charge the customer for the order.


You can try using the authorize Only method in Stripe : https://docs.stripe.com/connectors/adobe-commerce/configuration
https://prnt.sc/dzU4wYOKbhdV

You would need to do the following:

Configure your stripe module to use Authorize Only instead of Authorize and Capture: https://docs.stripe.com/connectors/adobe-commerce/configuration#payments

Update your order confirmation email templates for both guests and customers, to add a custom message letting them know Your order is on hold. We will get back to you once we confirm stock availability. You can override the default order email templates in the admin panel under Marketing > Email Templates

Once you have confirmed stock availability, invoice the order in the admin panel, which will capture the payment and send the invoice email to the customer

If the stock is unavailable, you would need to Void the payment for that order in the admin panel, which would remove the authorization hold from their Credit Card


